# $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{4n^{\frac{3}{2}}+(-1)^n \cdot\sqrt{n}}{8n+n \cdot \sqrt{n}}$

Tags: limits

what is the limit of
Limit of $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{4n^{\frac{3}{2}}+(-1)^n \cdot\sqrt{n}}{8n+n \cdot \sqrt{n}}$ ?

Since $(-1)^n$ is -1 for odd and +1 for equal n I would argue that you cannot tell the limit of this function because it is undefined.

Wolfram however argued that the limit might be 4, symbollab says it's undefined. Now I'm confused.

Would be nice if someone could explain it in an easy way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you break apart the fraction into two think about what happens to $|(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n}}{8n + n\cdot\sqrt{n}}|$

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $n\sqrt{n}$ and note that $n^{\frac{3}{2}} = n\sqrt{n}$ to get $ \frac{4n^{\frac{3}{2}} + (-1)^n \sqrt{n}}{8n + n\sqrt{n}} = \frac{4 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}}{\frac{8}{\sqrt{n}} + 1}$. Can you proceed?

Comment: @DominikKutek Sure, we have 2 cases. if n is odd, we have $\frac{-1}{n} = 0$, if n is even $\frac{1}{n} = 0$. We're left with $\frac{4+0}{\frac{8}{\sqrt{n}}+1}$. Since $\sqrt{n} \rightarrow \infty$ we conclude $\frac{8}{\infty} \rightarrow 0$. So we're left with $\frac{4}{1} = 4$.

Comment: In fact you don't even need to look at those two cases, because $0 \le \left| \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right| = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$. And I wouldn't "partially" solve limits, althought in this case it works, but in general you need to consider all terms containing $n$ at once, not doing them one by one (somekind of "generic" example is here $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. If you try to do it one by one, you'll get either $1$ or $+\infty$ as a limit, however the "true" limit here is $e$)

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{4n^{\frac{3}{2}}+(-1)^n \cdot\sqrt{n}}{8n+n \cdot \sqrt{n}}=$$
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{4+(-1)^n \cdot n^{-1}}{8n^{-1/2} +1} =\frac {4+0}{0+1}=4$$